# Converting CSV file to Java Objects (POJO) and send it to ActiveMQ queue

Tags: java, csv, apache-camel, bindy

My aim is to read the csv file, convert it to Java Objects (POJO) and send the Java Objects one by one to a JMS queue. Below is the code:

```java
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("file:src/main/resources?fileName=data.csv")               
    .unmarshal(bindy)
    .split(body())
    .to("file:src/main/resources/?fileName=equityfeeds.txt")
    .split().tokenize(",").streaming().to("jms:queue:javaobjects.upstream.queue");          
}
```

**Issues:**
1.When I execute the code no file(equityfeeds.txt) gets created and no objects goes to the queue. What's wrong? I don't need to do any processing right now. I just need to unmarshal the csv to POJOs and send the Java Objects one by one to the JMS queue.

**EquityFeeds (POJO)**

```
@CsvRecord(separator = ",", skipFirstLine = true)
public class EquityFeeds {
    
    @DataField(pos = 1) 
    private String externalTransactionId;
    
    @DataField(pos = 2)
    private String clientId;
    
    @DataField(pos = 3)
    private String securityId;
    
    @DataField(pos = 4)
    private String transactionType;
    
    @DataField(pos = 5, pattern = "dd/MM/YY")
    private Date transactionDate;
    
    @DataField(pos = 6)
    private float marketValue; 
    
    @DataField(pos = 7)
    private String priorityFlag;
```

Please kindly help. Please tell me where I am going wrong.

@pvpkiran:Below is my Camel Code for producer:

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("file:src/main/resources?fileName=data.csv")               
        .unmarshal(bindy)
        .split(body())
        .streaming().to("jms:queue:javaobjects.upstream.queue");
}
```

Below is my Consumer Code (Using JMS API):

```
@JmsListener(destination = "javaobjects.upstream.queue")
public void javaObjectsListener(final Message objectMessage) throws JMSException {
    Object messageData = null;
    if(objectMessage instanceof ObjectMessage) {
        ObjectMessage objMessage = (ObjectMessage) objectMessage;
        messageData = objMessage.getObject();
    }
    System.out.println("Object: "+messageData.toString());
}
```

I am not using Camel for consuming the JMS message. In the consumer I am using JMS API for consuming the message (as above). Also I am not testing the code. In the terminal in am getting `NullPointerException`. Also 2 message have gone into the DLQ giving the below Error Message:

```
java.lang.Throwable: Delivery[7] exceeds redelivery policy limit:RedeliveryPolicy {destination = null, collisionAvoidanceFactor = 0.15, maximumRedeliveries = 6, maximumRedeliveryDelay = -1, initialRedeliveryDelay = 1000, useCollisionAvoidance = false, useExponentialBackOff = false, backOffMultiplier = 5.0, redeliveryDelay = 1000, preDispatchCheck = true}, cause:null
```

Comment: what is `bindy` in this line `.unmarshal(bindy)` also can u give a sample csv

Comment: `final BindyCsvDataFormat bindy=new BindyCsvDataFormat(camelproject.EquityFeeds.class);`                                  sample csv **externalTransactionId,clientId,securityId,transactionType,transactionDate,marketValue,priorityFlag
SAPEXTXN1,GS,ICICI,BUY,23/11/13,101.9,Y
SAPEXTXN2,AS,REL,SELL,20/11/13,121.9,N  **

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This should work

```
from("file:src/main/resources?fileName=equityfeeds.csv")
                    .unmarshal(new BindyCsvDataFormat(EquityFeeds.class))
                    .split(body())
                    .streaming().to("jms:queue:javaobjects.upstream.queue");
// This route is for Testing
from("jms:queue:javaobjects.upstream.queue").to("bean:camelBeanComponent?method=processRoute");
```

And write a consumer component bean

```
@Component
public class CamelBeanComponent {
    public void processRoute(Exchange exchange) {
        System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody());
    }
}
```

This printed(You need to add `toString()` if you need output like this)

```
EquityFeeds(externalTransactionId=SAPEXTXN1, clientId=GS, securityId=ICICI, transactionType=BUY, transactionDate=Sun Dec 30 00:00:00 CET 2012, marketValue=101.9, priorityFlag=Y)
EquityFeeds(externalTransactionId=SAPEXTXN2, clientId=AS, securityId=REL, transactionType=SELL, transactionDate=Sun Dec 30 00:00:00 CET 2012, marketValue=121.9, priorityFlag=N)
```

If you use `.split().tokenize(",")` then, each field in each line(not complete line) is converted to EquityFeeds object (with other fields as null) is sent as a message to the queue

Comment: I changed my code as per your answer above to: `public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("file:src/main/resources?fileName=data.csv")    
    .unmarshal(bindy)
    .split(body())
    .streaming().to("jms:queue:javaobjects.upstream.queue");
   }`  All the message came into ActiveMQ but it seems that the csv messages are not correctly unmarshelled to Java Objects as when I am consuming them I am getting NullPointerException. Please kindly advise.

Comment: sure .. here is the code ...`@JmsListener(destination = "javaobjects.upstream.queue")
    public void javaObjectListener(final Message objectMessage) throws JMSException {
        Object messageData = null;
        if(objectMessage instanceof ObjectMessage) {
            ObjectMessage objMessage = (ObjectMessage) objectMessage;
            messageData = objMessage.getObject();
        }
        System.out.println("Object: "+messageData.toString());
    }`  I am getting NullPointerException for all the objects. Additionally I just noticed that 2 messages went to the **ActiveMQ.DLQ** .

Comment: you can edit the question and update the code, instead of commenting. If you are using camel, You do not need `@JmsListener`. Use the exact code I gave for testing. The queue messages will be read and sent to the method mentioned. In the example it is `camelBeanComponent::processRoute`

Comment: I just edited the question and updated the code. Let me know if any other info is required. Please guide me and help me overcome this issue.

Comment: as i said, get rid of `JmsListener` and create another route as I showed. Also update what are the pom dependecies that u r using for `JmsListener`

Comment: check this out on how to consume messages using `@JmsListener` https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jms

Comment: I don't want to use Camel for my Consumer. I am using JMS API for my consumer. It's a SpringBoot Application. Its using spring annotation - **import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;**

Comment: Okay. fair enough. This question was about "Converting CSV file to Java Objects (POJO) and send it to ActiveMQ queue" . I guess that is achieved(As you can see from my test route) So please accept the question. Checkout the tutorial and see why consuming is an issue. If there is a problem ask another question